# Adding keyup events to dynamically generated elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which creates text boxes dynamically and there is another button 'Clear'.

If there is no text in any of the text field then the clear button is disabled or else it will be enabled. It works for the text box that is created when the dom is loaded but for the dynamically created textboxes it does not work.

Here is the **HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" class="a" />
<input type="button" value="Clear" class="a" id="clearBasicSearch" />
<div id="basicSearchFields">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    $("#basicSearchFields").append("<input type='text' class='b' />");
});

/*$(".b").live("keyup", function () {
        //alert('you pressed ' + $(this).val());
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        });*/

var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input[type='text']");
$("#clearBasicSearch").removeClass('hidden').removeClass('button').attr('disabled', true);

toValidate.live('keyup', function () {
    console.log("hi");
    var valid = false; //default is false
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            valid = true; //non-empty element found
            return false; //break
        }
    });
    $("#clearBasicSearch").attr('disabled', !valid).toggleClass('button', valid);
});
```

JSfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/TpExS/

Please help me out!!

Comment: I can't use 'on' as I am using lower version of jquery

Comment: Upgrade your jquery version

Comment: BTW, as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() instead ! http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Even if you can't use `.on()`, if you're using >= 1.4.2 you can and should use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#basicSearchFields input[type='text']",function () {
    console.log("hi");
    var valid = false; //default is false
    var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input[type='text']");
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            valid = true; //non-empty element found
            return false; //break
        }
    });
    $("#clearBasicSearch").attr('disabled', !valid).toggleClass('button', valid);
});
```

Comment: I can't use 'on' as I am using a lower jquery version. I even can't update the jquery version as it might break other functionality.

Comment: Also can we create a function called 'validate' and do the stuff?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input#basicSearchFields",function () {  
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#basicSearchFields").delegate("input[type='text']", 'keyup', function () {
    validate();
});

function validate(){
    console.log("hi");
    var valid = false; //default is false
    var toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input[type='text']");
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            valid = true; //non-empty element found
            return false; //break
        }
    });
    $("#clearBasicSearch").attr('disabled', !valid).toggleClass('button', valid);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tcmYN/)

Comment: there is no 'live' in new jQuery versions try 'on'

Comment: @SreekeshOkky it is there in version 1.6 which is used by OP

Comment: Can we create a function as validate and do the same stuff?

Comment: use $("#basicSearchFields input:text")

Comment: If the OP is using 1.6 you should modify your code to use `.delegate()` rather than `.live()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/TpExS/2/

Note: JQuery 2.0.2 used

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fields = $('input[class=b]');
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        $(fields[i]).on('keyup', validateFields);
    }
});

$(".a").click(function () {
    var newField = $('<input/>').attr('type', 'text').attr('class', 'b');
    $(newField).on('keyup', validateFields);

    $("#basicSearchFields").append(newField);
});

function validateFields(){
    if($(this).val().length){
        $('#clearBasicSearch').attr('disabled', false);
        return;
    }

    $('#clearBasicSearch').attr('disabled', true);
    var fields = $('input[class=b]');
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        if($(fields[i]).val().length){
            $('#clearBasicSearch').attr('disabled', false);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, Updates your global "toValidate" variable when you add more elementson the click.

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    $("#basicSearchFields").append("<input type='text' class='b' />");
    toValidate = $("#basicSearchFields input:text");
});
```

Why? The time you set toValidate, it will return an array at that moment, you should updates it in each time there are new elements, or check for all of then inside the live event.